problema con el retorno valor de una funcion C++ intente con estructura pero me da error
float DHT_Task(void){
    struct readings DHT_reading = {0, 0};

        DHT_reading.result_code = DHT_Read(&DHT_reading.humidity, &DHT_reading.temperature);

        if(DHT_reading.result_code == SUCCESS)
        {
        printf("\r\nHumidity  =   %.2f\r\n",DHT_reading.humidity); 
        printf("\r\nTemperature  =   %.2f\r\n",DHT_reading.temperature);
            return DHT_reading.temperature , DHT_reading.humidity ;
        }   
}

EN MAIN TENGO
float x1;
float x2;
    x1 , x2 = DHT_Task();
    printf("Humidity: %f\n", x1);
    printf("Temperature: %f\n", x2);

struct readings
{
    float humidity;
    float temperature;
    uint8 result_code;
};

y obtengo en el primer codigo
Humidity  =   21.00
Temperature  =   19.00
y en el segundo
Humidity: 0.000000
Temperature: 1101529088.000000
nose porque tengo diferentes resultados

Si el if no se cumple, no retornas ninguna cosa.

Es C++, no Python. Por un lado, también debes devolver algo cuando el if no se cumple. Por otro, x1 , x2 solo asigna la variable x2, no hace destructuring como en Python. Además, con return DHT_reading.temperature, DHT_reading.humidity; solo devuelves la humedad. Por qué mejor no usas return DHT_reading?

Las expresiones x1 , x2 = DHT_Task(); y return DHT_reading.temperature , DHT_reading.humidity ; no hacen lo que crees que hacen. En ese caso estás usando el operador coma (operator,).
El operador coma funciona de la siguiente manera:

Evalúa la expresión a la izquierda de la coma y la descarta.
Evalúa la expresión a la derecha de la coma y la devuelve.

Por lo tanto en tu caso la expresión x1 , x2 = DHT_Task();:

Evalúa x1 y la descarta.
Evalúa x2 = DHT_Task() y devuelve x2.

Y la expresión return DHT_reading.temperature , DHT_reading.humidity ;:

Evalúa DHT_reading.temperature y la descarta.
Evalúa DHT_reading.humidity y devuelve DHT_reading.humidity.
La instrucción return devuelve el valor de DHT_reading.humidity.

Probablemente querías usar structured bindings:
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<float, float> f()
{
    return {0.1234f, 5.6789f};
}

int main()
{
    auto [a, b] = f();

    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << '\n';

    return 0;
}

El el código anterior, a obtiene el valor 0.1234f y b obtiene el valor 5.6789f, puedes verlo funcionando en Try it online!.
Ten en cuenta que las structured bindings son una característica de c++ sin embargo aunque hayas etiquetado la pregunta como tal, pareces estar programando en c.

En C y C++ sólo se puede devolver un valor, no más de uno. Sin embargo, si usas C++, se puede devolver una tupla, que contiene valores concatenados. Las tuplas se pueden desempacar en valores individuales usando std::tie().
Se debe notar que este código va a funcionar en c++11 o superior (es C++, no C). Además el usar tuplas para devolver valores no es computacionalmente eficiente cuando los objetos son pesados y es lento copiarlos. En ese caso, se le puede pasar los valores por referencia a la función.
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>

// Cosas a definir para que el código de ejemplo compile
typedef unsigned char uint8;
#define FAILURE 0
#define SUCCESS 1

struct readings
{
    float humidity;
    float temperature;
    uint8 result_code;
};

// Funcion de prueba para que el código de ejemplo compile
uint8 DHT_Read(float *humidity, float *temperature)
{
    *humidity = 2.0f;
    *temperature = 4.0f;
    return SUCCESS;
}

// La funcion devuelve una tupla con dos valores
std::tuple<float,float> DHT_Task(void)
{
    struct readings DHT_reading = {0, 0};

    DHT_reading.result_code = DHT_Read(&DHT_reading.humidity, &DHT_reading.temperature);

    if(DHT_reading.result_code == SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Humidity  =   %.2f\n",DHT_reading.humidity); 
        printf("Temperature  =   %.2f\n",DHT_reading.temperature);
        return {DHT_reading.temperature , DHT_reading.humidity};
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Humidity/temperature reading was not successful\n");
        return {-1,-1};  // Devolver algún valor por defecto que no sea valido (la humedad debe ser igual o mayor a cero)
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    float x1;
    float x2;
    std::tie(x1, x2) = DHT_Task();
    if (x1 >= 0)
    {
        printf("Humidity: %f\n", x1);
        printf("Temperature: %f\n", x2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Humidity/temperature not valid");
    }
    return 0;
}

